# PlayFramework : Include CKEditor?

Tags: playframework, ckeditor, twirl

I want to include a ckeditor in a *.scala.html view. 
But when i import ckeditor like the developper guide say, i've nothing.

Code full [here](http://pastebin.com/Nmyn4wxp):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <label class="control-label">Your Message</label>
            <p>
            <textarea id="editor" name="content" placeholder="Ecrivez votre message ici"></textarea>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
            </script>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end row -->
```

Result :

[image: Result of the code]

As you can see, nothing appear ! 
It's really strange. I think there are a few things to do to make it work !

Thanks you so much !

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No in fact i have uncompatible plugin so i've just do a simple installation of CKEDITOR and it work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is :

Plugin incompatible so I've install the default CKeditor and now ot work great !!